# Having trouble with whitespace and strings in a function

Tags: python, string, algorithm

Prompt

> Turn a string into rollercoaster case. The first letter of the sentence is uppercase, the next lowercase, the next uppercase, and so on.

Code

```
with open('test.txt') as file:
    for line in file:
        words = line.split()
        for word in words:
            chars = list(word)
            for index, char in enumerate(chars):
                if index == 0:
                    print char.upper(),
                elif is_even(index):
                    print char.upper(),
                elif is_odd(index):
                    print char,
```

Input

```
Sunshine makes me happy, on a cloudy day
```

Output

```
S u N s H i N e M a K e S M e H a P p Y , O n A C l O u D y D a Y
```

This is my first attempt at this problem. I can't think of any other way to do this other than to iterate by each letter. When I do this though I'm just treating the entire sentence as a string and spewing out characters.

Comment: "When I do this though I'm just treating the entire sentence as a string and spewing out characters." Is this a bad thing? Is this substantially different from what you're doing now?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can uppercase just every second letter with an extended slice, picking every second letter:

```
>>> sample = 'Sunshine makes me happy, on a cloudy day'
>>> sample[::2].upper()
'SNHN AE EHPY NACOD A'
>>> sample[1::2].lower()
'usiemksm ap,o  luydy'
```

Now all you need to do is put those together again:

```
from itertools import izip_longest

result = ''.join([l 
    for pair in izip_longest(sample[::2].upper(), sample[1::2].lower(), fillvalue='') 
    for l in pair])
```

`izip_longest()` pairs up the uppercased and lowercased strings again, making sure that if there is an odd number of characters to pad out the series with an empty string.

Demo:

```
>>> from itertools import izip_longest
>>> ''.join([l 
...     for pair in izip_longest(sample[::2].upper(), sample[1::2].lower(), fillvalue='') 
...     for l in pair])
'SuNsHiNe mAkEs mE HaPpY, oN A ClOuDy dAy'
```

Note that whitespace isn't ignored here; the `m` of `make` is lowercased even though the `e` at the end of `Sunshine` is too.

If you need to vary the letters more precisely, you can make use of iteration still:

```
from itertools import cycle
from operator import methodcaller

methods = cycle((methodcaller('upper'), methodcaller('lower')))
result = ''.join([next(methods)(c) if c.isalpha() else c for c in sample])
```

Here [`itertools.cycle()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.cycle) lets us alternate between two [`operator.methodcaller()` objects](https://docs.python.org/2/library/operator.html#operator.methodcaller), which either upper or lowercase the argument passed in. We only advance to the next one (using [`next()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#next)) when the character is a letter.

Demo:

```
>>> from itertools import cycle
>>> from operator import methodcaller
>>> methods = cycle((methodcaller('upper'), methodcaller('lower')))
>>> ''.join([next(methods)(c) if c.isalpha() else c for c in sample])
'SuNsHiNe MaKeS mE hApPy, On A cLoUdY dAy'
```

Comment: Given the title, though, it sounds like he may want to avoid whitespace.

Comment: Magic. I actually started off with having `sample[::2].upper()` but wasn't sure about how to put that back with the other one. Never tried izip_longest though, thanks for that. Nice implementation!

Answer (score 1):

If it's whitespace giving you trouble, you should use `isalpha()` to test if a character is a letter or not.

```
with open('test.txt') as file:
  for line in file:
    newstr = ""
    go_to_upper = True

    for c in line:
      if c.isalpha():
        if go_to_upper:
          newstr += c.upper()
        else:
          newstr += c.lower()
        go_to_upper = not go_to_upper
      else:
        newstr += c

  print newstr
```

Input: `Sunshine makes me happy, on a cloudy day`

Output: `SuNsHiNe MaKeS mE hApPy, On A cLoUdY dAy`

You'll only flip back and forth (using the `go_to_upper` boolean) when the character in question is a letter of the alphabet. Otherwise, it's outputted normally. Notice that `MaKeS` starts with a capital letter, though `SuNsHiNe` ends with a lowercase letter, even with the space in the way.

Also, instead of printing immediately (which gives you the weird spacing) we're putting our characters in a new list, which we'll print out all at once later.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code :

```
import re
i = 1
with open('test.txt') as file:
    for line in file:
        words = line.split()
        for word in words:
            chars = list(word)
            for index, char in enumerate(chars):
                if re.compile('[a-zA-Z]').search(char):
                    i+=1
                    if i%2 !=0:
                        print char.upper(),
                    else :
                        print char.lower(),
```